# Conditional addition of css - hook_init?

Tags: theming, hooks

I need to conditionally add css to a page  based on the page content / URL. In the past (D6 and down) I was always advised against using hook_init() mostly because of it's weird load order in the Drupal bootstrap process. It was not uncommon to see the hook fire multiple times on a each page load - this still might be the case.

Looking at the D7 docs for [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) the following code example is provided:

```
function hook_init() {
  // Since this file should only be loaded on the front page, it cannot be
  // declared in the info file.
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'foo') . '/foo.css');
  }
}
```

The example implies that conditional addition of css makes sense while:

> *To add CSS or JS that should be present on all pages, modules should
>   not implement this hook, but declare these files in their .info file.*

using a modules .info for site wide css additions.

**Questions**:

- What are the options in adding css via drupal_add_css conditionally
  besides hook_init?
- Has anyone had luck using the theme hook -> hook_html_head_alter():

  THEME_NAME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {

  ```
    if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
      drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'foo') . '/foo.css');
    }
  ```

  }
- or use the theme engine for the theme hook:

  phptemplate_html_head_alter(&$head_elements)

Answer (score 3):

If that CSS is in your module, then the module should really be implementing the hook.

I don't think you can do anything with CSS and JS in a [`hook_html_head_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7); that is really to mess with the render array before it is turned into `$head` by [`template_process_html()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7).  Personally, I would use a [`template_preprocess_html()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7).  You can add your logic there.  For example,

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.css');
  }
}
```

Comment: In terms of the module "implementing the hook", where in the module would you put drupal_add_css ? Would you use hook_init or some other function in the module?

Comment: I would implement it in template_preprocess_html.  Updated answer.